# Copy an external mp3 url link into a form and then uploaded to own server

Tags: php, mp3

Is there a way to copy an external mp3 url link, paste it in a form and once submitted it will be uploaded to own server using php?

Comment: What do you have, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: 42. The answer is 42!.. O wait, no. That's the answer to a *different* question. Sorry, all these vague questions are starting to fuse together. Getting hard to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at cURL.  You can use it to grab a remote file.  You will still need the URL, so you will have to parse the page using DOM or Regular Expressions.